# My jquery code for deleting an element upon clicking another element does not work

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to delete an entire section when the user clicks on a link that's inside the section. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:-

```
<section id = "intro">
    <h1> Hey There!</h1>
    <a href = "#" id = "button_intro"> Click here </a>
</section>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button_intro").click(function(){
    $("#intro").remove();
  }); 
});
```

The jQuery code is in a `.js` file which has been linked like this

```
<script src = "script.js" async> </script>
```

Comment: Have you included jquery.js in the page?

Comment: add this in your script also...https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works.

I think you forgot to load jquery.

load jquery in you html code.using this script tag `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id = "intro">
    <h1> Hey There!</h1>
    <a href = "#" id = "button_intro"> Click here </a>
</section>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#button_intro").click(function()
 {
  $("#intro").remove();
 }); 
});

</script>
```

Comment: Yes that's the issue. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have jquery library src? It works perfectly:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#button_intro").click(function()
 {
  $("#intro").remove();
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id = "intro">
    <h1> Hey There!</h1>
    <a href = "#" id = "button_intro"> Click here </a>
</section>
```